# Meteor server side debugging Webstorm 9 : fails when package nemo64:bootstrap has been installed

Tags: debugging, meteor, package, webstorm

After an upgrade to Webstorm 9 and Meteor 1.0 got everything working nice and smooth: code completion, server and client side debugging.

But server side debugging in Webstorm fails when I do install the Meteor package nemo64:bootstrap in my project.

The problem I do encounter : Webstorm is not able to connect to the server.

The strange thing here is : this happens only when I do activate Bootstrap components in the custom.bootstrap.json file (setting values to true). When all settings are false, the debugger runs just fine.

Webstorm Debug tab Console says:

/usr/local/bin/meteor --once
W20141118-23:49:20.518(1)? (STDERR) debugger listening on port 59485

Webstorm Debug tab Debugger says:
Cannot connect: Connection Refused

Anyone a solution or suggestion how to solve? 
The package nemo64:bootstrap does it's job (styling is visible in client browser). So it's reallly about the combination of Webstorm and the package.

Comment: FWIW: I manually opened Chrome and entered the port (per port listed in Web Storm console) and from then on it seemed to work.